# Compile Error cannot find symbol new Dashboard(); ^ symbol: class Dashboard location: class Main 1

Tags: java, swing, awt

So I'm trying to compile this program but I keep getting the error

```
Main.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
      new Dashboard();
          ^
  symbol:   class Dashboard
  location: class Main
1 error
```

I've tried looking at other similar posts trying out what they're doing but none of that worked for me. So I figured reinstalling my java installation would work (from jdk7 to jdk13), but I got the same results. I feel so stupid to ask what is probably a very easy oversight but I'm clueless. help me

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main implements ActionListener {
    private int clicks = 0;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Number of clicks:  0     ");
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public void Dashboard() {

       
        JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
        button.addActionListener(this);

        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);

        
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("GUI");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        clicks++;
        label.setText("Number of clicks:  " + clicks);
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Dashboard();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your class to `Dashboard` from `Main`, and change `public void Dashboard()` to `public Dashboard()` since its a constructor.